# While Trying Controller Unit Test for Create/EDIT operation in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I am trying to create Controller Unit Test for Create operation ,
not able to get the current User ID in order to call Create Controller action method from unit test function .
I got the error  " System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' "

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(TransactionCodeEditViewModel TransactionCodeViewModel)
        {
            TransactionCode transactioncode = new TransactionCode()
            {
               Number = TransactionCodeViewModel.Number,
                Name = TransactionCodeViewModel.Name,
                Description= TransactionCodeViewModel.Description,
                IsActive = true
            };
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _TransactionCodeService.Add(transactioncode, User.Identity.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

How will pass the value to  User.Identity.Name to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

User is a property on the Controller that just fronts the HttpContext.User.

If you are mocking out the dependencies of the controller, you can just return whatever IPrincipal you want.

This is an extension method I use to setup my controller (this example uses FakeItEasy)

```
    public static void SetControllerContext(this Controller controller)
    {
        var identity = A.Fake<IIdentity>();
        A.CallTo(() => identity.Name).Returns("your user name");
        var principal = A.Fake<IPrincipal>();
        A.CallTo(() => principal.Identity).Returns(identity);
        var fakeContext = A.Fake<HttpContextBase>();
        var fakeRequest = A.Fake<HttpRequestBase>();
        var fakeResponse = A.Fake<HttpResponseBase>();

        A.CallTo(() => fakeRequest.HttpMethod).Returns(HttpVerbs.Post.ToString());
        A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.Response).Returns(fakeResponse);
        A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.Request).Returns(fakeRequest);
        A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.User).Returns(principal);

        var fakeRequestContext = new RequestContext(fakeContext, new RouteData());

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(fakeRequestContext, controller);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Fakes setup, @Fran looks like a good solution. Here is one without Fakes:

Setup a shared class to reuse:

```
public class ControllerContextMock
{
    public ControllerContext GetContext(ControllerBase controllerBase)
    {
       var httpContext = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(string.Empty, "http://reason.com", null), new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
       var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), new RouteData());

       requestContext.HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("John Galt", "WindowsMock"), null));

       return new ControllerContext(requestContext, controllerBase); 
    }
}
```

Then call it from your Unit Test:

```
public void Index()
{
   // Arrange
   var controller = new HomeController();
   controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContextMock().GetContext(controller);

   // Act
   var result = controller.Create() as ViewResult;

   // Assert
   Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```